Using Radix-2 butterfly to combine 16 parallel 1024-FFTs into one 16384-FFT
I am struggling to understand combining multiple fast Fourier transforms into 1. Due to the architecture of the hardware I am using, I receive 16 samples per clock cycle in an FPGA. I can compute 16 individual FFTs for each super sample. I understand that a radix 2 butterfly architecture should be used (4 stages in this case) but don't understand what twiddle factors to use for each sample. Below is the architecture i believe is used.

However for the twiddle factors what do i use. For most cases i see it seems to talk about FFT sizes of 4 or 8 however mine is 16 1024 parallel ffts.
Also what order will the outputs be?
Could someone help me with this?

I'm still not clear what you are trying to do. 16 parallel 1k FFTs are different from one 16k FFT. Which one do you want in the end?

Apologies for the confusion. The incoming data to the fpga uses a supersampled architecture so there are 16 samples in parallel per clock. I am trying to create a 16k FFT output from 16 1k paralell ffts. The output is then 16 fft samples per clock. I understand it is possible to do however im struggling to wrap my head around combining 16 N/16 ffts into one N fft

Sorry, I still don't understand. The output of a 16k FFT are 16k samples, The output of a 1k FFT are 1k samples, They all come in one go. You can chop them up into frames of 16 samples later, but you still need to compute the entire 16k FFT completely before you can output anything.

In this case the samples are streamed in frames 16 samples at a time. The question is similar to this - link however I am quite confused
